# WSO2 - Uploading "Registry Resources Project" onto ESB Server

Tags: wso2, registry, esb

I have a requirement to version control my "registry" artifacts (i.e. wsdls, xsds, xsls), that I currently upload to the WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 server. I'm not using WSO2 GREG at the moment. I came across the "Registry Resources Project" facility which I think would help me achieve this. However I'm unsure as to whether this facility can only be used with GREG or with ESB as well. Is there a way for me to generate a CApp Project, include the the above "Registry Resources Project" in it, and deploy it to my ESB server?

I've come across [blogs](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/03/development-and-deployment-of-c-app-based-artifacts-on-multiple-environments/) which deploy standard ESB artifacts in the way, but not the registry. -

Please help....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create required registry resources as specified in the [creating registry resources documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS380/Creating+Governance+Registry+Artifacts#CreatingGovernanceRegistryArtifacts-Creatingregistryresources). Once you have created your registry resource project, then you need to create composite application archive as specified in the [Creating a Composite Application Archive (CAR) file documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS380/Packaging+Artifacts+Into+Deployable+Archives#PackagingArtifactsIntoDeployableArchives-CreatingaCompositeApplicationArchive(CAR)file).

When you are creating CAR file, you need to specify server role as **EnterpriseServiceBus** to deploy your registry resources in ESB.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I created a registry resource project with 1 HTTP Endpoint , created a composite application archive including registry resource project and upload it to ESB server successfully , how can I use it ?
I want to create a new project and reuse/import HTTP Endpoint in registry resource I uploaded above.